# How to eliminate slow scroll through all options in select multiple list in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I need to provide a button to allow users to select all options in a select multiple list box.

I am using jQuery to select the options.

In Internet Explorer 9, after the button is clicked, the browser displays a slow scroll effect through all of the options.

Sample code and the slow scroll are at http://jsfiddle.net/willdurman/4b7avgmm/12/

This effect is not present in the latest Firefox or Chrome.

How can this slow scroll affect be eliminated?

It's a requirement that the user is initially shown the list box with no options selected, then can select individual options or all options.

```
// Abbreviated list of 10 options
<select id="lb" multiple="multiple">  
    <option value="0">item number 0</option>
    <option value="1">item number 1</option>
    <option value="2">item number 2</option>
    <option value="3">item number 3</option>
    <option value="4">item number 4</option>
    <option value="5">item number 5</option>
    <option value="6">item number 6</option>
    <option value="7">item number 7</option>
    <option value="8">item number 8</option>
    <option value="9">item number 9</option>
</select>
<input type='button' id='selectAll' value ='Select All'/>

    // jQuery to select all options
    $(document).ready(function() { 
            $('#selectAll').click(function(e) {
                    $("#lb option").prop("selected",true);
            });
    });
```

Comment: Could you record, with a GIF, the effect? [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) is a great way to do so. [When I click the button](http://i.imgur.com/A5mFKLe.gif) in IE 9 all of the options are selected in much less than a second.

Comment: I can confirm that this happens in IE10, though it also finishes in less than a second. FF34 is instantaneous and I think that's what the OP is aiming for. Tried using $.val() but same effect happens. Not sure what can be done if this is a browser thing, but if the desired behavior is to start with all options selected and allow the user to deselect, then embedding the default selected state into the element seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/4b7avgmm/13/

Comment: It takes over three seconds for me in IE9. I will attach an animated gif or video when possible.

I will edit my question to clarify; typically the lists need to start with no options selected.

Comment: @Blackoak This sounds like a hardware issue. I doubt that we'll be able to find a way to speed up *this approach*. If you want instantaneous results you may need to take a different approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final implementation was much simpler. I simply wrap the selection process with a jQuery hide/show.

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 
      $('#selectAll').click(function(e) {
           $('#lb').hide();
           $("#lb option").prop("selected",true);
           $('#lb').show();
      });
 });
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4b7avgmm/17/

Answer (score 0):

I found that although the scroll effect is less noticeable on newer, faster machines, it is still present.

After much searching I found this Stack Overflow question [Dynamically select all items in a Multi-Select listbox using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230824/dynamically-select-all-items-in-a-multi-select-listbox-using-jquery). I adapted the code to work with my sample code:

```
var selectAllButton = document.getElementById('selectAll');
var listbox = document.getElementById('lb');

$(selectAllButton).click(function() { 
    selectAllOptions(listbox);
});

function selectAllOptions(listbox) {
var select = $(listbox);    
var clone = select.clone();
    $('option', clone).attr('selected', true);
    var html = clone.html();
    select.html(html);
}
```

Here's the updated JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/willdurman/4b7avgmm/19/. This approach causes no scrolling in Internet Explorer 9.